# Authentication Error when Building and Pushing docker image to ACR using Azure DevOps Pipelines and docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-container-registry, azure-devops-pipelines

I am trying to build and push a docker image to ACR using Azure DevOps pipelines. I have to build it with a docker-compose.yml file to be able to use openvpn in the container.

When I run the pipeline I get the following error. Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this?

```
Starting: DockerCompose
==============================================================================
Task         : Docker Compose
Description  : Build, push or run multi-container Docker applications. Task can be used with Docker or Azure Container registry.
Version      : 0.183.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azpipes-docker-compose-tsg
==============================================================================
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/docker-compose.yml -f /home/vsts/agents/2.188.2/.docker-compose.1624362077551.yml -p Compose up -d
Creating network "composeproject_default" with the default driver
Pulling getstatus (***/getstatus:)...
Head https://***/v2/getstatus/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.
##[error]Creating network "composeproject_default" with the default driver
##[error]Pulling getstatus (***/getstatus:)...
##[error]Head https://***/v2/getstatus/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.
##[error]The process '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: DockerCompose
```

My azure-pipelines.yml look like this:

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: '*****************************'
  imageRepository: 'getstatus'
  containerRegistry: 'composeproject.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'


stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)

    - task: DockerCompose@0
      inputs:
        containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
        dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
        action: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
        dockerComposeCommand: 'up -d'
```

And the docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: "3.3"
services: 
  getstatus:
    image: composeproject.azurecr.io/getstatus
    restart: always
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
    cap_add: 
      - NET_ADMIN
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun
    volumes:
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your docker compose task is [missing a couple of parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker-compose?view=azure-devops)

try adding `azureContainerRegistry: composeproject.azurecr.io`
and `azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)`

Not sure why the credentials supplied in the Docker@2 task don't persist since they're in the same stage but then I could fill an encyclopedia with what I'm not sure on when it comes to Azure pipelines